# Mailing a given string using jenkins code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to send an email with body text given in a string variable, and fail.
The line of code I use is:

```
mailtxt = 'ABCD'
emailext attachLog: false, subject:'$DEFAULT_SUBJECT' , to:'mymail@gmail.com' , replyTo:'$DEFAULT_REPLYTO', body: '''$mailtxt<div>'''
```

I have tried several combinations of code fences and $, but never get the string value.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The string variable can be addressed by `"${string}"`.
I suggest for you to read [the official Groovy language documentation](https://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html).

Comment: I have tried this combination too. Something is still not right.

Comment: ```emailext attachLog: false, subject:'$DEFAULT_SUBJECT' , to:'mymail@gmail.com' , replyTo:'$DEFAULT_REPLYTO', body: '${mailtxt}'
```
results in the text "${mailtxt}" being sent (and not the content)

Comment: need to use double or triple quote, body: "${mailtxt}",  reason can be found from here: https://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation